# $server_name not matching domain when multiple subdomains listed in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have the following server block defined:

```
server {
  server_name jsonip.com www.jsonip.com ipv4.jsonip.com ipv6.jsonip.com;
  add_header x-domain-name "$server_name $http_host $host" always;
}
```

I'm setting the 'x-domain-name' header simply as a way to test what nginx is seeing and reflecting it back to the browser.

The issue I'm having is that if I access https://ipv4.jsonip.com, then $server_name is matching 'jsonip.com' rather than 'ipv4.jsonip.com'.

Conversely, both $http_host and $host are matching the domains correctly.

Is there a different way to configure the server_name domains in the server block to get $server_name to match correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31479341/nginx-server-directive-with-multiple-server-name-entries-always-first-one-i

Comment: @tim Thanks for the link but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: No, `$server_name` doesn't work like that.

Comment: @Geuis I think it might work like that. It's pretty easy to try it and see.

Comment: @MichaelHampton please remove the duplicate question flag. This question is *not* a duplicate of the one that Tim linked to.

Comment: Of course not. It's a duplicate of the one I linked to.